# How to creat a loop ans stay at the same line without spaces in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops

for example, I want to print
01234567
so I know I need to write

```
for i in range(8)
 print(i),
```

and it will print 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
instead of change the line for every number
but I want it whithout spaces

Comment: I got along
`out=""
for i in range(8):
  out+=str(i)
print out
`

Answer (score 0):

You can use some Python 3 features in Python 2:

```
from __future__ import print_function

for i in range(8):
    print(i, end='')
```

Output:

```
01234567
```

Comment: It doesn't working for python 2

Comment: Forgot to copy the most important part.